# Cyrillic letter "ч." appears after clock on iOS 12

Tags: iphone, clock, ios

I have this quite strange issue after upgrading to iOS 12. Right after the clock appear a cyrillic "ч." symbol. I know that it stand there for "час", which is "hour" translated from my native language to English but this is very frustrating to look at. I have make two screenshots:

On the lock screen:

[image]

On an unlocked screen:

[image]

I am with iPhone X and iOS12. Does anyone else faced this problem? Does someone know how to remove this extra symbol after the clock? I have tried literally everything, so any ideas are great welcomed!

Comment: Have same problem, this is ridiculous, now hate looking at my phone! Hope some1 know how to remove this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I did so :
**settings/language & region/iPhone Language/English(UK)**
My phone was already with this option but I chose it anyway and luckily the symbol get disappeared. I hope I helped. Good luck.

Comment: This is quite strange, mine iPhone was set to English(UK) too, I just reapplied the setting and indeed the additional symbol disapear! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is related to the device language settings. I just tried to change language of my iPhone to Bulgarian (I guess it is Bulgarian on your screenshot) and the Cyrillic "ч" appeared after the time.
If you believe this is incorrect — drop Apple a feedback or bug report.

Comment: Hey Munas, thank you for the suggestion and yes it is Bulgarian. The thing is that, I have navigate to Settings -> General -> Language & Region and changed the region from Bulgaria to few other non-cyrillic regions, reseted the iPhone but the extra symbol still appears. 

"The iPhone Language" option is set to English. The "Preferred Language Order" is first English and then Bulgarian (I have tried to remove Bulgarian, nothing changed).

By any chance do you look at other settings and if yes, could you please share more info on them? Thank you.